# How to perform subtraction 1 with column value

Tags: scala, azure-databricks

I was stuck with perform an subtraction operation on withColumn in scala.

```
val result = finalJoinedDf.withColumn("CTF", when(col("VPC") === null or col("FreightExpense") === null or col("FreightRevenue") === null or col("Cost") === null,  null)
                                  .otherwise(1 - col("VPC").cast(DoubleType)/100))
```

My issues is that I'm unable to perform this subtraction it is giving the following error.

[image]

Even I'm unable to perform addition also.

Please someone help me here

Comment: try to use `1.0` instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf, when, lit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType
import spark.implicits._

case class Test(VPC: Option[Int])

val df = Seq(Test(Some(1)), Test(Some(2)), Test(Some(3)), Test(None)).toDF()

val testUdf = udf((a: Double) => 1 - a / 100)

val df1 = df.withColumn("CTF", when(col("VPC").isNull,  lit(null).cast(DoubleType))
  .otherwise(testUdf(col("VPC").cast(DoubleType))))

df1.printSchema()
//  root
//  |-- VPC: integer (nullable = true)
//  |-- CTF: double (nullable = true)

df1.show(false)
//  +----+----+
//  |VPC |CTF |
//  +----+----+
//  |1   |0.99|
//  |2   |0.98|
//  |3   |0.97|
//  |null|null|
//  +----+----+
```